# Escape special characters in insert (from dynamically created table) in ormlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, special-characters, ormlite

I am using C#, I created a table, using ServiceStack.OrmLite, corresponding to a class type created in run-time. To be clear, I did the following:

- After creating the type in runtime (employeeType), I could do the following:

`db.CreateTableIfNotExists(employeeType);`

This would create the table Employee corresponding to the (dynamically created type "Employee").

- In fact, my problem is that the Employee table column names contain some special characters (like: %, / ...etc.). Creating the table worked well as I've just described, but when I try to insert a row in this table, I had an exception due to a syntax error in the SQL statement (due to special characters found in the column names). The excption that I had is the following (check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAPwV.png)):

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection: Incorrect syntax near '('.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@TokenRequestsPerSec_Request\"."`

For info, the name of a column that I have in the table is "TokenRequestsPerSec_Request\Seconds" so the problem is with the "\"

I used the following to insert a column in Employee table:

`var typedApi = db.CreateTypedApi(employeeType);`

`typedApi.Insert(employeeInstance);`

Please check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtfPV.png) to see the insert statement executed by OrmLite to SQL server:

`exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO "ScanADFS" ("MonitoredObjectId","ScanDate","ScanDateInMs","EntityStatus","SystemServiceStatus","CertificateServiceStatus","FederationServiceStatus",
"CpuUsage_Percentage","RamAvailable_MB","DiskTime_Percentage","AverageDiskQueueLength","SystemPingTime_ms","CertificateSigningExpirationDate","CertificateTokenDecryptingExpirationDate",
"CertificateServiceCommunicationsExpirationDate","TokenRequests","TokenRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second","ArtifactResolutionRequests_ms","ArtifactResolutionRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second",
"ExternalAuthenticationFailures","ExtranetAccountLockouts","FederationMetaDataRequests","FederationMetaDataRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second","FederatedAuthenticationFailures","PasswordChangeFailedRequests",
"PasswordChangeSuccessfulRequests","SystemPingTest","SystemPowershellPerformanceCountersTest","SystemWindowsServicesTest","SystemCpuTest","SystemRamTest","SystemDiskTimeTest","SystemAverageDiskQueueTest",
"SystemDiskSpaceTest","CertificateTest","FederationTest","SystemPingThreshold_ms","CpuThreshold_Percentage","RamThreshold_MB","DiskTimeThreshold_Percentage","AverageDiskQueueLengthThreshold",
"CertificateValidityThreshold_Days") VALUES 
(@MonitoredObjectId,@ScanDate,@ScanDateInMs,@EntityStatus,@SystemServiceStatus,@CertificateServiceStatus,@FederationServiceStatus,@CpuUsage_Percentage,@RamAvailable_MB,@DiskTime_Percentage,
@AverageDiskQueueLength,@SystemPingTime_ms,@CertificateSigningExpirationDate,@CertificateTokenDecryptingExpirationDate,@CertificateServiceCommunicationsExpirationDate,@TokenRequests,
@TokenRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second,@ArtifactResolutionRequests_ms,@ArtifactResolutionRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second,@ExternalAuthenticationFailures,@ExtranetAccountLockouts,
@FederationMetaDataRequests,@FederationMetaDataRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second,@FederatedAuthenticationFailures,@PasswordChangeFailedRequests,@PasswordChangeSuccessfulRequests,
@SystemPingTest,@SystemPowershellPerformanceCountersTest,@SystemWindowsServicesTest,@SystemCpuTest,@SystemRamTest,@SystemDiskTimeTest,@SystemAverageDiskQueueTest,@SystemDiskSpaceTest,
@CertificateTest,@FederationTest,@SystemPingThreshold_ms,@CpuThreshold_Percentage,@RamThreshold_MB,@DiskTimeThreshold_Percentage,@AverageDiskQueueLengthThreshold,@CertificateValidityThreshold_Days)'
,N'@MonitoredObjectId 
int,@ScanDate datetime,@ScanDateInMs bigint,@EntityStatus varchar(7),@SystemServiceStatus varchar(7),@CertificateServiceStatus varchar(2),@FederationServiceStatus varchar(2),@CpuUsage_Percentage float,@RamAvailable_MB float,@DiskTime_Percentage 
float,@AverageDiskQueueLength float,@SystemPingTime_ms float,@CertificateSigningExpirationDate varchar(21),@CertificateTokenDecryptingExpirationDate varchar(21),@CertificateServiceCommunicationsExpirationDate varchar(19),@TokenRequests 
float,@TokenRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second float,@ArtifactResolutionRequests_ms float,@ArtifactResolutionRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second float,@ExternalAuthenticationFailures float,@ExtranetAccountLockouts float,@FederationMetaDataRequests 
float,@FederationMetaDataRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second float,@FederatedAuthenticationFailures float,@PasswordChangeFailedRequests float,@PasswordChangeSuccessfulRequests float,@SystemPingTest varchar(2),@SystemPowershellPerformanceCountersTest 
varchar(2),@SystemWindowsServicesTest varchar(2),@SystemCpuTest varchar(2),@SystemRamTest varchar(2),@SystemDiskTimeTest varchar(2),@SystemAverageDiskQueueTest varchar(2),@SystemDiskSpaceTest float,@CertificateTest varchar(2),@FederationTest varchar(2),@SystemPingThreshold_ms float,@CpuThreshold_Percentage float,@RamThreshold_MB float,@DiskTimeThreshold_Percentage float,@AverageDiskQueueLengthThreshold float,@CertificateValidityThreshold_Days float',
@MonitoredObjectId=2,@ScanDate='2017-08-07 15:27:48',@ScanDateInMs=1502112468000,@EntityStatus='Warning',@SystemServiceStatus='Warning',@CertificateServiceStatus='Up',@FederationServiceStatus='Up',@CpuUsage_Percentage=36,719999999999999,@RamAvailable_MB=592,@DiskTime_Percentage=0,@AverageDiskQueueLength=0,@SystemPingTime_ms=1,@CertificateSigningExpirationDate='5/21/2018 12:49:00 AM',@CertificateTokenDecryptingExpirationDate='5/21/2018 12:48:55 AM',@CertificateServiceCommunicationsExpirationDate='6/9/2018 5:31:25 PM',@TokenRequests=0,@TokenRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second=0,@ArtifactResolutionRequests_ms=0,@ArtifactResolutionRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second=0,@ExternalAuthenticationFailures=0,@ExtranetAccountLockouts=0,@FederationMetaDataRequests=63876,@FederationMetaDataRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second=1,@FederatedAuthenticationFailures=0,@PasswordChangeFailedRequests=0,@PasswordChangeSuccessfulRequests=0,@SystemPingTest='Up',@SystemPowershellPerformanceCountersTest='Up',@SystemWindowsServicesTest='Up',@SystemCpuTest='Up',@SystemRamTest='Up',@SystemDiskTimeTest='Up',@SystemAverageDiskQueueTest='Up',@SystemDiskSpaceTest=2,@CertificateTest='Up',@FederationTest='Up',@SystemPingThreshold_ms=275,@CpuThreshold_Percentage=80,@RamThreshold_MB=500,@DiskTimeThreshold_Percentage=90,@AverageDiskQueueLengthThreshold=2,@CertificateValidityThreshold_Days=30`

Is there a solution to escape special characters in OrmLite insert statement?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection: Incorrect syntax near '('.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@TokenRequestsPerSec_Request\"."

For info, the name of a column that I have in the table is "TokenRequestsPerSec_Request\Seconds" so the problem is with the "\"

Comment: @mjwills it's a long insert statement that OrmLite has generated :)

`exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO "ScanADFS" ("MonitoredObjectId","ScanDate","ScanDateInMs","EntityStatus","SystemServiceStatus","CertificateServiceStatus","FederationServiceStatus",
"CpuUsage_Percentage","RamAvailable_MB","DiskTime_Percentage","AverageDiskQueueLength","SystemPingTime_ms","CertificateSigningExpirationDate","CertificateTokenDecryptingExpirationDate",
"CertificateServiceCommunicationsExpirationDate","TokenRequests","TokenRequestsPerSec_Request(s)/Second","ArtifactResolutionRequests_ms"`

Comment: Please include it in your post @Adel .

Comment: I cannot write everything is one comment because the statement is too long

Comment: I included it in my post, please check the link in the post.

Comment: Please include the full text of the SQL insert that causes the exception in your post.

Comment: What version of `ServiceStack.OrmLite` are you running?

Comment: I am running v4.0.30319

Comment: Does it work if you upgrade to the latest https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

String query = "Select * from users where id = ? ORDER BY \"usernum#\"";

or

select * from test order by "username#" desc;